# Akka actor system with HTTP interface

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm trying to create an Akka system which would among other things respond to HTTP requests. I created a few actors who exchange messages fine. I can also use akka-http to respond to HTTP requests. The problem is in connecting those two parts.

TL;DR: **How to talk to Akka actors during akka-http request processing?**

I created a single actor responsible for bringing up the HTTP system:

```
class HttpActor extends Actor with ActorLogging  {
  /* implicits elided */

  private def initHttp() = {
    val route: Route =  path("status") { get { complete { "OK" } } }
    Http()(context.system).bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
  }
  private var bound: Option[Future[Http.ServerBinding]] = None

  override def receive = {
    case HttpActor.Init =>
      bound match {
        case Some(x) => log.warning("Http already bootstrapping")
        case None =>
          bound = Some(initHttp(watcher))
      }

  }
}

object HttpActor {
  case object Init
}
```

As you may see, the actor creates the akka-http service on the first message it receives (no reason, really, it could do it in the constructor as well).

Now, during the request processing I need to communicate with some other actors, and I can't get it working.

My approach:

```
  private def initInteractiveHttp() = {
    val route: Route =  path("status") { 
      get { complete { "OK" } } 
    } ~ path("ask") {
      get { complete {
        // Here are the interesting two lines:
        val otherActorResponse = someOtherActor ? SomeMessage
        otherActorResponse.mapTo[String]
    } }
    Http()(context.system).bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
  }
```

This would send a `SomeMessage` to `someOtherActor` and wait for response prior to completing the Request-Response cycle. As I understand, however, that messages would be sent from the root `HttpActor`, which is bad and leads nowhere in terms of scalability. Ideally I would create a distinct instance of specialized actor for every request, but this fails due to akka-http typing. Consider the following example:

```
class DisposableActor(httpContext: HttpContext) {
    override def preStart() = {
       // ... send some questions to other actors
    }
    override def receive = {
      case GotAllData(x) => httpContext.complete(x)
    }
}

class HttpActorWithDisposables {
  // there is a `context` value in scope - we're an actor, after all
  private def initHttpWithDisposableActors() = {
    val route: Route =  path("status") { 
      get { complete { "OK" } } 
    } ~ path("ask") {
      get { httpContext =>
        val props = Props(new DisposableActor(httpContext))
        val disposableActor = context.actorOf(props, "disposable-actor-name")
        // I have nothing to return here
      }
    }
    Http()(context.system).bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
  }
```

With this approach, I can force the DisposableActor to call `httpContext.complete` at some point of time. This should correctly end the Request-Response processing cycle. The Route DSL, however, requires to return a valid response (or Future) inside the `get` block, so this approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first approach is quite alright, actually.
The ask pattern creates a lightweight, disposable actor for you that waits on the result (non-blockingly) to complete the future. It basically does all the things you want to replicate with the `DisposableActor` and your main HttpActor is not stressed by this.

If you still want to use a different actor, there is [`completeWith`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.2/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/marshalling-directives/completeWith.html):

```
completeWith(instanceOf[String]) { complete =>
  // complete is of type String => Unit
  val props = Props(new DisposableActor(complete))
  val disposableActor = context.actorOf(props, "disposable-actor-name")

  // completeWith expects you to return unit
}
```

And in you actor, call the complete function when you have the result

```
class DisposableActor(complete: String => Unit) {
  override def receive = {
    case GotAllData(x) => 
      complete(x)
      context stop self // don't for get to stop the actor
  }
}
```